# Add textbox via dynamic imagebutton in a panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, panel, imagebutton

I have a problem I seem to stumble over all the time, I have a Drop Down box and you can select a number which creates x number of textboxes with images buttons its for a survey it the image buttons are used to create "Sub-Answers" so they can have answers to answers so my question is I need to when they hit the image button to create a textbox under the orginal textbox here is the code.

```
for (Int32 i = 1; i <= NumberOfAnwsers; i++)
{
Literal l1 = new Literal();
l1.Text = "<tr><td>Answer " + i + " text.</td><td>";

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "TextBoxAnswer" + i;
tb.EnableViewState = false;
tb.Width = 300;

Literal l3 = new Literal();
l3.Text = "</td><td>";

Literal l2 = new Literal();
l2.Text = "</td></tr>";

RadColorPicker CPI = new RadColorPicker();
CPI.PaletteModes = PaletteModes.WebPalette;
CPI.ID = "RadColorPicker" + i;
CPI.ShowIcon = true;
CPI.SelectedColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

ImageButton IBVideo = new ImageButton();
IBVideo.ID = "IBVideo" + i;
IBVideo.ImageUrl = "/images/video-icon.jpg";
IBVideo.ToolTip = "Add Video";
IBVideo.Height = 20;
IBVideo.Width = 20;

ImageButton IBAdd = new ImageButton();
IBAdd.ID = "IBAdd" + i;
IBAdd.ImageUrl = "/images/add-icon.png";
IBAdd.ToolTip = "Add Sub-Answers";
//IBAdd.OnClientClick = "showDialog(" + i + ");return false;";
IBAdd.Height = 20;
IBAdd.Width = 20;

//Add Textbox

PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(l1);
PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(tb);
PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(l3);
PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(CPI);
PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(IBVideo);
PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(IBAdd);
PanelAnswersToQuestions.Controls.Add(l2);
}
```

As you can see I just add controls to the panel, I need to know when that ImageBUtton is hit I can add a Textbox and in this case it could be more then just one textbox to it.

I hope this is clear but for some reason I dont think it is ... sorry.

Comment: You'll need an to subscribe an event handler to the image button(s), However, you will also need to be mindful or the creation of the control hierarchy and ensure this is in place every time before any events for the consequent controls are handled.  In summary you need to ensure that all of your items are created BEFORE any events are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I got your question right but if you need to dynamically add controls on a Page here is what I can say.

Before adding your control I guess you need to find the control where you need to add it on, Add the control then assign the properties.

```
PlaceHolder myPlaceHolder = (PlaceHolder)Page.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");

myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myButton);
myButton.Text = "Hello World";
```

For a more detailed expalnation go here http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/dynamically-removing-controls-in-a-parent-page-from-a-child-control/

Comment: I have changed some of this around I now just added it to a radwindow and I am having an issue with Javascript finding a dynamic hiddenfield

Answer (score 0):

I have added a radwindow and poping that up sending the Data to the partent via javascript the which created a new problem for me, I can not in javascript seem to find the dynamicly created hiddenfield

```
function OnClientClose(radWindow) {
        var oWnd = $find("<%=RadWindowAddSubAnswer.ClientID%>");
        var SubAnswerValues = oWnd.get_contentFrame().contentWindow.document.forms(0).HiddenFieldSubAnswers.value;
        alert(SubAnswerValues);
        var AnswerID = oWnd.get_contentFrame().contentWindow.document.forms(0).HiddenFieldAnswerID.value;
        alert(AnswerID);
        var HiddenName = "HiddenFieldSubAnswers" + AnswerID;
        alert(HiddenName);
        document.getElementById(HiddenName).value = SubAnswerValues; 
        $get("DivSubAnswers" + AnswerID).innerHTML = SubAnswerValues;
    }
```

The "document.getElementById(HiddenName).value = SubAnswerValues;" seems to never be found, I also tried $get(HiddenName).value = SubAnswerValues; that does not seem to work either both come back as null as for the code behind its: 
    HiddenField HFSubAnswers = new HiddenField();
    HFSubAnswers.ID = "HiddenFieldSubAnswers" + i;
HFSubAnswers.Value = "0";